# How to do React Native-style multiple version builds for React with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

**Motivation**

I am maintaining an app that is white-labelled for numerous separate brands, which vary mainly in style but also sometimes in core UX. The current (Backbone) solution involves keeping shared code in a separate repo and then building the separate apps with Grunt, with much of the style code and some view overrides for each project living in its own folder. We simply run all the grunt tasks one after the other using a shell script. We're going to build new versions of this thing in React going forward and want to minimize duplicate code, which has now become a major problem in the legacy version.

**Desired outcome**

The React Native packager builds two versions of its app at the same time. It looks at an import statement like `import ComponentA from './ComponentA.js'` and goes looking for either `ComponentA.android.js` or `ComponentA.ios.js` first, then falls back to importing `ComponentA.js` if it doesn't find a platform-specific one. I would like to replicate this behavior in Webpack. So I would like to have a folder that looks like this:

```
react_clients/src/components
  |_ ComponentB.js // import ComponentA from './ComponentA.js';
  |_ ComponentA.js
  |_ ComponentA.brand1.js
  |_ ComponentA.brand2.js
```

Webpack should build `ComponentB.js` as follows:

- `brand1.bundle.js` imports from `ComponentA.brand1.js`
- `brand2.bundle.js` imports from `ComponentA.brand2.js`
- `brand3.bundle.js` and `brand4.bundle.js` import from `ComponentA.js`

This would also apply to styles, ideally with the same naming convention.

If necessary, Webpack could be run separately for each version, either using different webpack.config files or accepting command line arguments. The key thing is to avoid duplicating application code.

**Current code**

The starting point for Webpack is a freshly-generated and ejected `create-react-app` project.

---

PS: Apologies in advance if this turns out to be a duplicate but this has been a very tricky question to research. I suspect the answer will have something to do with an advanced configuration of https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/ but can't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright folks here's what I ended up doing:

**Dev**

In `.env.development` I specify a variable for the name of the project I want to do dev on:

```
REACT_APP_VERSION_NAME=brand1
```

Then in `webpack.config.dev.js` I take advantage of module resolution to achieve the behavior described above:

```
const JS_PROJECT_EXTENSION = `.${process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION_NAME}.js`;
const STYLE_PROJECT_EXTENSION = `.${process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION_NAME}.pcss`;
const extensions = [JS_PROJECT_EXTENSION, '.js', '.json', '.jsx', STYLE_PROJECT_EXTENSION, '.pcss'];

...
module.exports = {
...
  extensions,
...
}
```

Then in the code I can simply do the following:

```
import ComponentA from './componentA';
import Styles from './styles';
```

And everything works as expected.

---

**Production**

I don't specify `REACT_APP_VERSION_NAME` in `.env.production`. Instead the relevant config files export functions, and I iterate over the versions I want to build.

First, I created a separate version of `config/paths.js` that exports a function instead of a static object:

```
module.exports = function(projectName) {
  return {
    ...
    appBuild: resolveApp('build/' + projectName),
    ...
  };
}
```

And my `webpack.config.prod.js` looks like this:

```
...
const getPaths = require('./paths.prod');
...

module.exports = function(projectName) {
  const paths = getPaths(projectName);

  const JS_PROJECT_EXTENSION = `.${projectName}.js`;
  const STYLE_PROJECT_EXTENSION = `.${projectName}.pcss`;
  const extensions = [JS_PROJECT_EXTENSION, '.js', '.json', '.jsx', STYLE_PROJECT_EXTENSION, '.pcss'];

  ...
  return {
    ...
    output: {
      ...
      filename: projectName + '-assets/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
      chunkFilename: projectName + '-assets/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
      ...
    }
    ... [etc, adding projectName to any output that needs to be built separately]
  };
}
```

Finally, just wrap most of the action in `scripts/build.js` in a loop:

```
...
[various imports]
...

process.argv[2].split(' ').forEach(projectName => {
  const config = require('../config/webpack.config.prod')(projectName);
  const paths = require('../config/paths.prod')(projectName);
  ...
  [rest of build.js as normal]
}
```

After that it's just a matter of pointing your server at the right files for each version, and running `yarn build "brand1 brand2"` when you want to build.

Going to accept this answer since it's working for me for now but would love to hear about potential improvements from anyone who comes across it in the future.